# How to use proximity weight modifier to affect particles density and shapekeys

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, shape-keys

previously it was possible to trick blender with a simple node setup within the sorcar addon for the proximity weight modifier to work with either particles density or shapekeys , for example in an animation we want a dynamic part of an object to emit particles or we want a dynamic part of an object changes shape which changes through time , it seems like the sorcar addon was possible to reconstruct the object for each frame so that tricked the software to work with dynamic paint or dynamic weight any ways .

for what i want to know , i want to know that is there any node setup within blender's geometry nodesetup to trick blender for the same thing, to bypass blender limits in this field .

also i kind of don't like any other workarounds for this matter or i don't want to defy the whole geometry shapekey or particles definitions inside geometry nodes since idon't have time to learn all those new stuff , im good with old tools that i had ...

anyways, im pretty sure that there is a node setup that can bypass this lock and let the shapekeys for example read the weight after proximity weight or for the particle system's density vertex group to read the weight data after the modifier or after the dynamic paint ( or work with it), any help and suggestions are appreciated .

Comment: a quick update , I do have found a workaround for the particle matter and that is the use of textures and dynamic paint instead of weight idk if it works with cycles or not , but i don't like it either i want it to be the true way

Comment: just adding one other note for fire simulations and etc we can use mask modifier to limit the emission dynamically and for the hair we can use length VG dynamically